# onbeforeunload / onunload when user reset/shut down computer

Tags: php, mysql, dom-events, onbeforeunload, window.onunload

I have a field in my database that register if a window is open.

I also have a `onbeforeunload` / `onunload` function that delete this cell when user close the window.

The problem is when the user "reset" / "shut down" the computer that the query is not sent and I don't know why.

Can you help me?

Comment: because window isn't closed ?

Comment: But how can I solve this issue?

Comment: you have no issue. Your database waiting for the window to be closed. When hard-resetting computing the window is not closed. Nothing is wrong, programmatically

Comment: What I have to do to delete the cell in the database also when user does a hard-reset? Thank you.